# Java App Engine Tic Tac Toe example Serve image

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I don't know what the heck is going on but I cloned google's GAE Tic Tac Toe example directly into eclipse using this address:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java

And i cannot serve an jpg from the images folder for the life of me. A gif serves fine.  But not jpgs.  Any jpg brings up a 404 error.

Please, someone... tell me I am not crazy.

Comment: and yes, i have added a <static-files> and it is doing absolutely nothing.  There has to be something going on behind the scenes in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing question.  Was too specific of an issue to be useful to anyone else.  Had some kind of permissions error on my folder when i got it from github.  Don't know who that could have happened but chmod -R 777 on the folder fixed everything.

Comment: guess i can't close this yet.  Move along, nothiing to see heere :D